# How to avoid duplicate events in socket.io when you are working with multiple tabs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, socket.io

When i receive message from server `ditConsumer` based on flag i am invoking a function `sendMessageToFile()` that is working as expected, problem here is when i navigate to other page and come back again so here when message comes in socket.on is listening twice and executing all variables and method twice. if i go back and forth three time it will listen 3 times, I would appreciate help here, it looks like socket.io connection problem over multiple tabs.

ctrll.js

```
      socket.on('ditConsumer',function (data) {
            console.log('SEND MESSAGE FLAG',sendMessageFlag)
            console.log('MESSAGE FROM SERVER',data);
            var obj = {
                file:$scope.filename,
                data:data
            }
            $scope.event.push(data);
           // socket.emit('messageToFile',obj);
            if(sendMessageFlag === true) {
               return  sendMessageToFile(obj);
            }
        });

   function sendMessageToFile (data){
         if(data.file) {
             socket.emit('startrecording', data);
             $scope.disabledRecBtn = true;
             $scope.disabledStopBtn = false;
             $scope.showMessage = true;
         }
    }
```

socketFactory.js

```
angular.module('loggingApp').factory('socket', function($rootScope) {
    'use strict';
    var server = 'http://localhost:3000';
    var socket = io.connect(server, {
        'forceNew': true
    });
    return {
        on: function(eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function() {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    };

});
```

serverIo.js

```
var sio = require('socket.io');
var ditconsumer = require('./consumers/ditconsumer');
var logsRecording = require('./records/logsRecording');
var io = null;
exports.io = function () {
    return io;
};
exports.initialize = function(server) {
    io = sio(server);
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        // Producer.startProducer();
        ditconsumer.start(function(value){
         io.emit('ditConsumer',value);
         });
        socket.on('createlogfile', function(params) {
            logsRecording.userLogs(function(err,filename) {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    socket.emit('filename', filename);
                }
            });

        });
        socket.on('startrecording', function(obj) {
            logsRecording.recordLogs(obj);
        });
        socket.on('stopRecording',function (filename) {
            console.log('stop recording data',filename);
            logsRecording.deleteFile(filename);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to...

```
// add an event_id to the event message on server-side
io.sockets.emit('my_event', {msg:'hi', event_id: '1'});

// on client side keep track of handled events
var acknowledged = [];

// handle event
io.on('my_event', function (msg) {

    // only continue if the event hasn't been handled before
    if(!~acknowledged.indexOf(msg.event_id)){

        // add to array of acknowledged events
        acknowledged.unshift(msg.event_id);

        // prevent array from growing to large
        if(acknowledged.length > 20){
            acknowledged.length = 20;
        }

        // handle once per event
    }
});
```

You might also want to utilize socket.io rooms and create unique identifiers for ever every connection or create something like an uuid and store it in the localstorage space of the browser; read or create it and supply it when connection to io. Then when you send an event you could target specific rooms.

Or do something similar.....